# Create a List of Widgets, where each widget holds three attributes

Tags: posts, pages, widgets, blog

i have a specific wordpress page, in which I want to add expandable items.
So the item has a keyword and when I press it, it expands and more specific text will show up.
The styling and setup of such an element is not the problem, but how can I implement it that way, that I can edit the keyword and the content in the front end?

I cant use blogposts, as they are used in my blog.

One element is supposed to hold the following attributes: Keyword, more specific text, Link
And the page shall show many of those elements.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: are you describing an accordion?

Comment: @TomJNowell yea exactly :) But how can I make its data editable in the frontend?

Comment: have you looked for accordion blocks? Why does it need to be editable from the frontend?  Can you provide more context? Do you know about custom post types?

Comment: @TomJNowell No I haven´t yet, but it seems to be a good solution. I will look into that. Thanks. It needs to be editable from the front end, as the page should also be maintainable by people who are not into coding. I also dont know about custom post types :( The context: I am doing a website for a company and they want the pages to be easily editable without any programming skills required.

Comment: @TomJNowell Hey Tom, is it possible to contact you somehow? I have a few questions as I am new to wordpress. Would be realy cool of you